# VS2015 - LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0'

Tags: visual-studio, gstreamer

Today I wanted to implement Gstreamer on vs2015 community version on Windows 10.

I included Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories 
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\glib-2.0\glib C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\glib-2.0\ C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\include\gstreamer-1.0\
**C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include**

3 of them which is under \include directories are worked without error. However, only from **\lib\glib-2.0\include** gives error.

I configured library correctly for make you sure

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories and Properties -> Linker -> Input-> Additional Dependencies on the libraries that I will use such as gstreamer-1.0.lib;gobject-2.0.lib;glib-2.0.lib;

I connected everything correctly because in my compiler I can reach the header file glibconfig.h which was under '**C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0**' and also other header files.

However compiler gives this error.

**LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0'**

I wrote the same code on Qt Creator , it did not give such errors but I did not output like video. Therefore, I wanted to try it on Visual Studio. So I don't think there is a permission issue from LNK1104 error.

If anyone can help, that would be so cool.

Comment: Can it be that you give in this path in the linker command? It expects a library name but you give it a path..

Comment: gstreamer consists of one header file called glibconfig.h in /lib directory. I surprised that too but it has. I found a solution I will share in minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Choose debug as x64.

Don't forget to look up whether you're using x64 or x86 debug if you are having my problem.

The explanation of the Error **"LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0"** is complicating so you might not find what is the problem.

Thanks,